# Картинка долго грузится с сервера

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

*Возможно мой вопрос дубликат. Я этого не отрицаю*

На моем сайте я добавил много картинок и попробовал через Photoshop их размер оптимизировать, но так, чтобы картинки оставались четкими при оптимизации. Какие другие есть способы для моментальной загрузки на сайт картинок (может с помощью js frameworks, или css...)?

Скорость загрузки, как видно на картинке снизу, превышает 0,5s.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если скорость интернета медленная, то никак вы этот мегабайт не оптимизируете, кроме как дальнейшим уменьшением размера картинок

Answer (score 0):

Какую роль выполняют картинки? Если это элементы интерфейса, то могу предложить преобразовать их с помощью base64 в код и так использовать. [Вот хороший ресурс для этого](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/imagetobase64/). А если это часть контента, с которым предполагается взаимодействие пользователей (сохранение, например), то можно попробовать поискать реализации с Lazy Load.

Comment: Целый мегабайт в base64? А вы смелый)

Comment: @andreymal в сервисе ограничение до пяти стоит, так что почему бы нет

Comment: base64 попробую как доберусь до рабочего компьютера. А вот lazy load - интересная вещ для изучения. Может быт полезна.